# Knockout.js applyBindings twice duplicate result

Tags: knockout.js

HTML

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<thead>
    <tr><th width="483"><span>Product Name</span></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind='foreach: basket.model.products()'>
    <tr><td><div class="ml10 productDetails" data-bind="text: name"></div></td></tr>            
</tbody>
</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
var ProductLine = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.name         = ko.observable(data.name);

};

function BasketModel(data) {
    var self                = this;                     
    self.initialData        = ko.observable(data);      
    self.products           = ko.observableArray();

    $.each(self.initialData().products,function(i,val){
        self.products.push(new ProductLine(this));
    });
}
function renderBasket(data){        

    basket = { model: new BasketModel(data)};
    ko.applyBindings(basket.model);
}   
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sampleData = [{"name":"product 1"},{"name":"product 2"}];
    renderBasket(sampleData );
});
```

When i add a new product to basket within ajax post , i call the function below with response data

```
renderBasket(response.data);
```

Example response.data like
     [{"name":"product 1"},{"name":"product 2"}, {"name":"product 3"}];

At first:
table rows are like :

```
 product 1
 product 2
 product 3
```

AFTER i add a new product 
result is :

```
product 1
product 1
product 1
product 2
product 2
product 2
product 3
product 3
product 3
```

I've tried ko.cleanNode and basket.model.products.removeAll() before ko.applyBindings(basket.model);
But i couldn't solve it.

Thank you.

Comment: When i have done this on "ajax post success" and it worked. But I think that should not be the real solution. basket.model.products.removeAll();
      
      $.each(ajaxCevap.data.products,function(i,val){
       basket.model.products.push(new ProductLine(this));
      });

Comment: You should never call `applyBindings` twice, and you should never call `cleanNode` unless you know what you are doing (it is not necessary for nearly all standard use cases). This question gets asked at least once a month. Please go through the [Knockout Tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call `ko.applyBindings` only once (from the `$(document).ready` function). Just push the products on the observableArray, and you're good to go.

See http://jsfiddle.net/yCBJ8/5/ for the full example.

```
var ProductLine = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    },
    BasketModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;

        self.products = ko.observableArray();

        self.addToBasket = function (d) {
            $.each(d, function (i, v) {
                self.products.push(new ProductLine(this));
            });
        };

        self.replaceBasket = function (d) {
            self.products.removeAll();
            self.addToBasket(d);
        };

        self.addToBasket(data);
    };

$(document).ready(function () {
    var initialData = [{"name": "product 1"}, {"name": "product 2"}],
        basket = {
            model: new BasketModel(initialData)
        };

    ko.applyBindings(basket.model);
});
```

Comment: There is an, error addToBasket' of object [object Object] is not a function . But I got the idea Thank you so much.